# What makes git rev-list slow(er), and how to make it go faster?

Tags: git, performance

I've retrieved some performance logs from a Bitbucket server and see that a large portion of time is spent executing 'git rev-list --format=... --no-walk=unsorted ...hash...'. Average time to run it is 0.9s, sometimes longer.

1. How does 'git rev-list' performance scale? O(revisions)? O(files)?
2. What can I do about it? (Software or hardware)

Answer (score 2):

The answer to question 1 is very complicated as it depends on the options given.  However, your particular command includes:

```
--no-walk=unsorted
```

which means that not only does the rev-list command *not* walk the commit graph (which is where most time is mostly spent for most `git rev-list` commands), it also does not even sort the objects specified on the command line (which eliminates a call to a sort algorithm; sorting is generally O(n log n) in the number of items be be sorted—for most `--no-walk` `git rev-list` commands, n would be quite small here anyway).

In this case, then, the performance of `git rev-list` will be dominated by looking up the hash IDs of objects specified on the command line, and by formatting those objects with the `--format` directive.  It's likely that the former is the slow part: the commit objects must be obtained from disk (as loose objects or members of a pack object).  The speed of that will be determined by what's in your OS's cache, how effective that cache is, the number of loose and packed objects, the number of packs, and so on.

There was a recent performance fix to Git for use in repositories with more than 50 pack files.  If you have >50 object pack files and don't have this version of Git, upgrading your Git would be the quickest fix for that.  You might also be able to run `git repack` to reduce the number of pack files.

Comment: Yup. All that command is doing is loading the pack maps and dumping the requested data.  Batching the command, to do all the hashes at once, would cut a huge fraction of the overhead.  Depending on what's in that format a `git cat-file --batch-check` might be best.